# How do I check on how many parts is a matrix divided in

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a matrix made out of zeroes and ones. I need a way to see how many "zero blocks" there are. Here's a picture to better illustrate:

[image]

In this example there are 4 "zero blocks" divided by the black blocks (ones in the matrix).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you can use dfs to find components in a graph. Here is a classic code example working on a grid where X means a wall and 0 means free space (black and white squares in your case):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using Map = std::vector<std::string>;
using BoolMap = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>;

void dfs(BoolMap& visited, int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || y >= visited.size() || x >= visited[y].size())
        return;
    if (visited[y][x]) 
        return;

    visited[y][x] = true;
    dfs(visited, x - 1, y);
    dfs(visited, x + 1, y);
    dfs(visited, x, y - 1);
    dfs(visited, x, y + 1);
}

int main()
{
    Map map;
    map.emplace_back("0X00");
    map.emplace_back("XXX0");
    map.emplace_back("0X0X");
    map.emplace_back("0X00");

    BoolMap visited(map.size());
    for (size_t y = 0; y < map.size(); y++)
    {
        visited[y].resize(map[y].size());
        for (size_t x = 0; x < map[y].size(); x++)
        {
            // set visited to true if there is a wall
            visited[y][x] = (map[y][x] == 'X');
        }
   }

    size_t component_count = 0;

    for (size_t y = 0; y < map.size(); y++)
    {
         for (size_t x = 0; x < map[y].size(); x++)
        {
            if (!visited[y][x])
            {
                dfs(visited, x, y);
                component_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << component_count << std::endl;
}
```

This code can be simplier if you know that your map is always a square one (map.size() can be used instead of map[y].size()). Also I loop through the map twice to check for a walls but if it is not too big there should not be a performance issue.

If you are already working with a boolean matrix and it is okay to change it you can just pass it as a visited parameter and the algorithm will work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at BFS & DFS for graph traversal. You can represent your matrix as a graph where every cell is connected to its neighbors in the 4 directions: North, South, East and west.

If you have a problem, let me know in the comments for more details.

Comment: @E.N.D Why not good answer? I'm not supposed to write the whole code for the problem (although I can do so because I implemented this problem many times before). I gave the best approach and algorithms for the problem, and that's more important than the code itself.